# Silverlight RichTextBox does not pick up background

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a popup window like this,

```
<controls:ChildWindow Background="Aquamarine">
    <RichTextBox>
        <Paragraph x:Name="WarningMessage" >
            <Run>Test 1234</Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBox>
</controls:ChildWindow>
```

I've removed most of the xaml for clarity, but the problem is that I have set the child window to have a background of Aquamarine, but the rich text box control still has a white background.

Is there any way to make the rich text control use the colour of the parent control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichTextBox's template defines default background as white. To change it you have to set Background property of the RichTextBox to different color. In your case "Transparent" color will do the trick.

```
<RichTextBox Background="Transparent">
...
```

Comment: I don't see this actually working.  Nothing I do changes the background from white.